A question about the relation between uniform continuous map and Cauchy sequence.
Suppose $X,Y$ are metric spaces, $f:X\to{Y}$ is a map.
If $X$ is compact metric space, we know $f$ is a uniform continuous map $\Leftrightarrow$ for all Cauchy sequence $x_n$, $f(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence.
But, if we don't have the condition that $X$ is compact, is this proposition still right?

It's still right, because the only thing that matters is that f is unimorm continuous.

A bit of grammatical pedantry: "uniform" is an adjective, so the phrase "uniform continuous" presents "uniform" and "continuous" as both being adjectives modifying "map". But there's no such thing as a "uniform map". Rather, we have "uniformly continuous maps" where "uniformly" is an adverb modifying "continuous", not "map". That is, "uniformly" tells us what type of continuity we have, not what kind of map we have.

Assuming your question is regarding the biconditional statement

$f$ is a uniformly continuous map if and only if for every Cauchy sequence
$\{x_n\}$, $\{f(x_n)\}$ is a Cauchy sequence (Cauchy continuous)

No, the proposition is not correct if $X$ isn't compact. Just consider $X=\mathbb{R}$ and $f(x)=x^2$. Note $f$ is not uniformly continuous but $f$ is Cauchy continuous as $\mathbb{R}$ is complete and $f$ is continuous—every continuous function is sequentially continuous which combined with the completeness gives Cauchy continuous.
If $\{f(x_n)\}$ is Cauchy in $Y$ for every Cauchy sequence $\{x_n\}$ in $X$, then $f$ is continuous. Now if $X$ is compact, then every continuous function is uniformly continuous.
